# Pusher Test Nofitifcations - Angular 2

Tags: angular, pusher

I am currently having a tutorial using the third party application , Pusher for sending real time notification. I am able to send events and receive the notifications of the client side but my problem is, i want the notification to be tracked in a notification tab after it has sent. Once it pops up, it has to be in the notification to keep track of. 
As it appears in the image, the event is being fired, but it has to also appear in the notification tab. Is it possible to fetch the sent events from the pusher dashboard.

**nofitication tab**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-user">
        <li class="dropdown messages-dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>  Notifications <b class="caret"></b>
            <span class="label label-danger">10</span>
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown-header"></li>
            <li class="message-preview">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="avatar"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i></span>
                <span class="message">Message from facebook</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="message-preview">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="avatar"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i></span>
                <span class="message">Message from twitter</span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">See all  Messages</a></li>
          </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would reverse your problem and (re-)structure your app:

Build a **notification service**, where you can add (read, remove ..) notifications. This is the only class where notifications can be created with pusher. The notification service keeps track of the (count of) notifications. Also you can/should use RxJS to make your service subscribable.

Your notification tab subscribes to your notification service and is therefore informed if there are changes, like an added notification or the removal of a notification.

The benefits of this approaches are:

- You have **one** notification service, which can be easily injected into a component, to give them the ability to create new notifications
- You only have to implement the usage of pusher once and you can easily replace or extend the visualization of notifications
- Your notification count and tab will be up to date, wherever you create a notification.

This approach implies considerable more work, but will pay out when your app grows.

Comment: There is push notication and toast notification in angular 2. I am familiar with the toast notification, is that a good notification service that work with pusher?

Comment: Push notifications and toast notifications are not angular exclusive ;) . At the end of the day you have to decide which will fulfill your requirements. The visual representation of a notification is only your choice and not depending on the usage of the pusher api.